# Customizing class for element of error message only in jQuery Validation plugin

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-validate

In jQuery Validate plugin, setting `errorClass` sets both error message and input element's class. Is there anyway to set class for error message element only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the plugin dynamically adds the `errorClass` to both the input and the error message element *and you cannot change this behavior*, nor would you need to change it.  After all, having classes on elements does nothing until you create some CSS properties that targets them.

So by using the correct CSS selectors, you can easily target these elements individually.

The default `label` container for validation messages along with the default `errorClass` setting, which is `"error"`...

```
label.error {
    /* CSS properties targeting only the error messages */
}

select.error,
textarea.error,
input[type="text"].error,
input[type="radio"].error,
input[type="checkbox"].error {
    /* CSS properties targeting only the input elements */
}
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/j3te0d10/**

---

> Is there anyway to set class for error message element only?

You wouldn't ever need to do this.

Just target `label.error` in your CSS and only the error messages are affected.

```
label.error {
    /* CSS properties targeting only the error messages */
}
```

**DEMO 2:  http://jsfiddle.net/j3te0d10/1/**